# Why is this unordered list formatting differently in IE7?

Tags: css, html-lists, internet-explorer-7

I'm better about getting things to look good in IE8, FF, and Safari, but IE7 still throws curve balls at me...

Please check out this page and scroll down below the nav bar:
http://rattletree.com/instruments.php

It should become obvious when viewing in FF vs IE7.  For some reason the formatting of the list is pushing the list items down on the page...
any tips?

```
<ul class="instrument">

      <li class="imagebox"><img src="/images/stuff.jpg" width="247" height="228" alt="Matepe" /></li>
      <li class="textbox"><h3>Matepe</h3><p>This text should be to the right of the image but drops below the image in IE7</p></li>
 </ul>
```

css:

```
ul.instrument {
   text-align:left; 
     display:inline-block;

}

ul.instrument li {
   list-style-type: none;
     display:inline-block;

}

li.imagebox {
 display:inline;    
 margin:20px 0; 
 padding:0px;
 vertical-align:top;

}

li.imagebox img{
 border: solid black 1px;
}

li.textbox {
 display:inline;     
}

li.textbox p{
margin:10px;
    width:340px;
    display:inline-block;   
}
```

Comment: looks the same in FF and IE7 to me.

Comment: really?!?  Looks the same?  I'm using IE8 and the Dev tools to toggle to IE7 and formatting changes...Text should be to the right of the pics but drops below in IE7 here...

Comment: Using IE8 to view in IE7 mode is not the same as actually using IE7.  I have noticed quite a few differences.

Comment: Is text to the right of the image or below?

Comment: This is what I see: http://i865.photobucket.com/albums/ab219/tster123/rattletree.png

Comment: Sorry to not be more clear...Scroll down the page.  The unordered list is below the header and nav bar.-correcting my question to be more clear.

Comment: I was looking at the menu, not the content area.  I see the difference.

Comment: I don't have time to check this, but make the ul display:block, and the li elements display:inline

Comment: That doesn't work-just breaks the other browsers layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically this line `ul.instrument li {`  is overiding `li.imagebox etc.`

so what you can do is this:

CSS:

```
ul.instrument {
    text-align:left; 
    display:inline-block;
}
ul.instrument li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display:inline-block;
}
ul.instrument li.imagebox {
    display:inline;    
    margin:20px 0; 
    padding:0px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
ul.instrument li.imagebox img{
    border: solid black 1px;
}
ul.instrument li.textbox {
    display:inline;     
}
ul.instrument li.textbox p{
    margin:10px;
    width:340px;
    display:inline-block;   
}
```

Basically what I did, instead of declaring `li.imagebox` I used `ul.instrument li.imagebox`
so that it won't be overide by this declaration `ul.instrument li`

Hope this helps :)

Edit, here's another take but this approach is different it uses float

CSS:

```
ul, li, h3, p { margin: 0; padding: 0 }
ul, li { list-style: none }
ul.instrument { overflow: hidden}
ul.instrument li, ul.instrument li img { float: left; }
ul.instrument li.imagebox { margin:20px 0;  }
ul.instrument li.imagebox img { border: 1px solid black }
ul.instrument li.textbox p { margin: 10px; width: 340px }
```

but this one works in all browsers, I promise :D.  Basically the first 2 lines resets the elements you used so that it will look the same in all browser.

Comment: Well dang-that made it WORK in IE7, but NOT work in the other browsers!!  :-D

Comment: updated / edited the answer, my 2nd take works on all browsers :)

Comment: Ah-great!  yes-all I needed to do ws put that float in there, and all is working great.  Thanks!